# Where are libvirt's VM definitions "originals" stored, and how to sync them across multiple nodes?

Tags: libvirt, cluster, xen, pacemaker

Migrating from Xen's `xm` to Xen's `xl` under control of libvirt, I wonder:

Where does libvirt store the "originals" of VM configurations?

I found that my PVM configurations are stored in `/etc/libvirt/libxl/`, but when viewing such files I see a comment saying that file has been created automatically and I should not be edited ("use virsh edit ...").
I also found XML and JSON files in `/var/lib/xen`, named after the Domain ID and UUID of the VM.

As I'm configuring a HA cluster, I'd like to synchronize VM configurations across all cluster nodes (allowing live-migration).
In the past syncing `/etc/xen/vm` was enough, but for libvirt it seems to be much more complicated:
Sometimes I'll have to `virsh define` a VM from the XML file, `virsh destroy` does not only destroy the running VM, but also the configuration it seems, and `virsh undefine` also removed the XML file in `/etc/libvirt/libxl/` it seems.
I don't know how to synchronize the configuration across the cluster nodes.

The major problem I see is this:
After csync2-ing the XML files defining the VM configurations to the other cluster nodes, I see the changes in the `/etc/libvirt/libxl/` files, saying "do not edit; use `virsh edit` instead".

However when I use `virsh edit` for one of those files, the contents I see in the editor is not what I see in the XML files located in `/etc/libvirt/libxl/`.

Maybe re-phrase the question to:
*If I update the XML files in `/etc/libvirt/libxl/` (like via `csync2`), how can I ensure that libvirt uses the updated configurations?*

### Update

This question became more important after I had added a block device for paging using `xl block-attach` corresponding to the edited configuration.
When the VM was live-migrated to another node in the cluster, the added disk was not transferred to the VM, so the VM froze when trying to access that disk.
So obviously the configuration of the current machine was not used for live-migration, and the saved configuration in the XML files weren't used either.

Comment: Do you use something like openstack for VM deployment? If the answer is yes, please add that to your question, because openstack builds those xml definitions based on a couple of settings.

Comment: So I'll have to add that I don't use openstack? May configurations were created either by `virsh domxml-from-native xen-xm`, or by `virt-install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the way "I don't care any more":

I created an extra copy of the configurations that I edit any sync in `/etc/xen/vm/`.
As the cluster RA `VirtualDomain` creates the VM newly from the configuration file given, I just specify that copy, and so I don't have to care any more where `libvirt` stores the actual VM configuration.